# Endless 301 redirection with Sonata Admin Bundle Symfony 2.7

Tags: .htaccess, symfony, sonata-admin

I'm trying to secure the admin panel of SonataAdminBundle by forcing the https scheme for my App hosted on Heroku. I have followed the official [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/cookbook/routing/scheme.html) with the following changes :

in *app/config/routing.yml*, I have added **schemes: [https]** :

```
app_admin:
    resource: "@AppAdminBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    schemes: [https]
    prefix:   /
```

And in *app/config/security.yml*, I have :

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/[a-z][a-z]/$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/[a-z][a-z]/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN, requires_channel: https }
```

Finally my *.htaccess* contains this :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Now whenever I try to access the admin panel, I am stuck in an endless 301 redirection. See attached picture :
[image: Endless 301 redirection]

I had no trouble accessing the admin panel before. Has anybody encountered this before?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem seemed to come from the fact that I did not configure Symfony to work behind a load balancer/proxy which is mandatory when using Heroku.

See :

[Symfony Cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/cookbook/request/load_balancer_reverse_proxy.html)

[Heroku Best Practices](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-symfony#trusting-the-load-balancer)